# Spiders in Judaism

Tags: bugs

I'm interested in  sources regarding spiders from any jewish source, preferably ones that portray them as 'good'.
For example, I remember seeing they are called 'Buchya' in aramit since they are found at desolate places, crying on the Churban. (בוכיא as in בכי)

Comment: I heard from a granddaughter of R' Chaim Shmulevitz that spiders are evil (and should therefore be killed) because they are cruel. I do not know the source for this assertion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mishlei 30:28](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16401/jewish/Chapter-30.htm#v=28&showrashi=true):

> שְׂמָמִית בְּיָדַיִם תְּתַפֵּשׂ וְהִיא בְּהֵיכְלֵי מֶלֶךְ
>
> The spider grasps with [her] hands, and she is in a king's palaces.

This is one of the four animals that are called חֲכָמִים מְחֻכָּמִים - exceedingly wise.

Footnote: Spider is a common translation in a large number of traditional sources, and it is the one Rashi uses. There are, however, [other opinions](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8:%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%9C_%D7%9B%D7%97), either a small lizard (which is now the scholarly popular opinion, apparently) or a monkey (Ibn Ezra).

Targum to Tehilim 57:3 is quoted as the source for the famous Medrash that a spider saved Dovid HaMelech's life, which [practically an industry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0911643192) at this point.

In [Perek Shira](http://www.tfilah.org/perek_shira/), it is associated with [Tehilim 150:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16371#showrashi=true&v=5).

[Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42494&st=&pgnum=143&hilite=) is a very long piece discussing that portion of Perek Shira with many different aspects of the symbolism of a spider.

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://shortvort.com/shemini-parasha/12081-parshas-shemini)

> The Medrash ‘Alpha Beta Di’ Ben Sirah’ relates a story where King
>   David asked Hashem why he created spiders for ‘they are such ugly and
>   useless creatures’. Hashem responded ‘be patient, a day will come when
>   you’ll want to kiss one’. Some time later David had to hide in a cave
>   from King Saul who wanted to kill him. As Saul’s search party
>   approached his cave, Hashem sent a spider which spun a big web across
>   its entrance. When Saul saw the unbroken web he surmised that no one
>   had entered there and continued his search elsewhere. When David
>   realized what had transpired, he found the spider and gave it a
>   grateful kiss! Hashem was teaching David that although it may not be
>   obvious why each creature was created; they in fact all exist to serve
>   a purpose.

Your reference to the term בוכיא is in

Sukkah 52a:24:

> יצה"ר בתחילה דומה לחוט של **בוכיא** ולבסוף דומה כעבותות העגלה שנאמר
>   (ישעיהו ה, יח) הוי מושכי העון בחבלי השוא וכעבות העגלה חטאה
>
> The Evil Inclination is at first like the thread of a **spider**, but
>   ultimately becomes like cart ropes, as it is said, “Woe unto them that
>   draw iniquity with cords of vanity, and sin as it were with a
>   cart-rope” (Isaiah 8:18).

Comment: Also fun: the related midrash regarding David HaMelech and mosquitoes

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - U and I have been "busy" today ;-) I'm unfamiliar with this one. Same Midrash location? Otherwise, can you link the above?

Comment: Not sure, but predicated on the same concept re: David not understanding the purpose of creation.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - Yes, there are a number of them like that. Another famous one that I recall, deals with his not understanding the purpose of craziness / madness, until David had to use it himself when he was hiding in Avimelech's territory.